# Writing a correct assertion test for equal arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, assertion

I'm having trouble writing a correct assertion test. It works fine on single arrays but it doesn't work when testing an array of arrays. The problem seems to be with `areEqualItems` but I don't know why. What am I doing wrong?

```
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName){
    var areEqualLength = actual.length === expected.length;
    var areEqualItems = actual.every(function(item, i){
        return item === expected[i]
    });
    if(areEqualLength && areEqualItems){
        console.log('passed');
    } else {
        console.log('FALIED [' + testName + '] Expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual);
    }
}

var arr1 = [0,1,2,3];
var arr2 = [0,1,2,3];

var arr3 = [ [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3] ];
var arr4 = [ [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3] ];

assertArraysEqual(arr1, arr2, 'arrays should be equal'); // passed
assertArraysEqual(arr3, arr4, 'arrays should be equal'); // FALIED [arrays should be equal] Expected 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3, but got 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3
```

Comment: You need to make it recursive.

Comment: Well the simplest answer is that in JS [] === [] = false, Means that you can not compare object or array. you will need to detect them and then deep compare them meaning what @Barmar said, You will need to recursively check if they are equal as well. Also, this approach is kinda bad as you are not checking if the same value might be in a different index of the array so even if the array is equal but shuffled you will always get false

Comment: So basically testing equality of two arrays is not the same as testing the equality of an array of arrays?

Comment: So... what you're saying is I should scrap this approach and start over? :)

Comment: @Barmar how would I go about making it recursive?

Comment: @I0_ol that is exactly what it means. To check arrays or object you will need to re-index their value if they are equal and then the simplest way is just to check if after re-indexing the count value are identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make it recurse if the element is another array.

Also, there's no point in checking if the items are equal when the lengths don't match.

It would also be better if you took the logging out of the comparison function. I had to make it conditional on whether the `testName` argument was supplied, so that it wouldn't log during all the recursive calls.

```js
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  var areEqualLength = actual.length === expected.length;
  var areEqualItems = areEqualLength && actual.every(function(item, i) {

    if (Array.isArray(item) && Array.isArray(expected[i])) {
      return assertArraysEqual(item, expected[i]);
    } else {
      return item === expected[i]
    }
  });
  if (testName) {
    if (areEqualItems) {
      console.log('passed');
    } else {
      console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual);
    }
  }
  return areEqualItems;
}

var arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [0, 1, 2, 3];

var arr3 = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
];
var arr4 = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 1, 2, 3]
];
var arr5 = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [0, 2, 3, 4]
];

assertArraysEqual(arr1, arr2, 'arrays should be equal'); // passed
assertArraysEqual(arr3, arr4, 'arrays should be equal'); // FALIED [arrays should be equal] Expected 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3, but got 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3
assertArraysEqual(arr3, arr5, 'arrays should not be equal');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a very succinct equals function. Just check the edge cases where the lengths aren't equal or they aren't arrays and then recurse:

```js
var arr3 = [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]];
var arr4 = [[0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]];


function equal(a, b){
  if (!Array.isArray(a) || !Array.isArray(b)) return a === b
  if (a.length !== b.length) return false

  return a.every((item, i) => equal(item, b[i]))
}

console.log(equal(arr3, arr4))
console.log(equal([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little help on how to make it recursive:

```
function areArraySame(one, two) {
    var length = one.length === two.length;
    var allElems = one.every(function(item, i) {
        if (item instanceof Array) {
            return areArraySame(item, two[i]); // <-- recurse!
        }
        return item === two[i];
    });

    return length && allElems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you stringify the arrays and then compare? It will reduce your code significantly take a look.

```
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected) {
    const actualStr = JSON.stringify(actual);
    const expectedStr = JSON.stringify(expected);
    return actualStr === expectedStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution to let this job to a third party, which can be for example lodash.

Lodash has isEqual method which can do the job for you.

Check out the documentation [here](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual).

*Sample code:*

```
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
    if (_.isEqual(actual, expected)) {
        console.log('passed');
    } else {
        console.log(`FALIED [${testName}] Expected ${expected}, but got ${actual}`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the arrays (and their child arrays, and their child arrays) can become very expensive quite quickly. In addition the code you wrote, as well as the accepted answer, don't take into account associative arrays (aka objects). I would suggest converting both of the arrays into JSON strings and then compare them as strings.

```js
function assertArraysEqual(actual, expected, testName){
    if ( actual.length === expected.length && JSON.stringify(actual) == JSON.stringify(expected) ) console.log('passed');
    else console.log('FALIED [' + testName + '] Expected ' + expected + ', but got ' + actual);
}

var arr1 = [0,1,2,3];
var arr2 = [0,1,2,3];

var arr3 = [ [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3] ];
var arr4 = [ [0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3] ];

assertArraysEqual(arr1, arr2, 'arrays should be equal'); 
assertArraysEqual(arr3, arr4, 'arrays should be equal');
```